# Wix toolset: registry key not deleted after uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using wix to write an installer for my x64 app. So the wxs looks like this:

```
<Package Id="*" Platform="x64" ...
```

And I'm running `candle` with `-arch x64`. However, I need to write a registry key to communicate with a 32 bit app under `Software\WOW6432Node\MyCompany\MyKey`, so I have a component like this:

```
<Component Id="SomeId" Guid="SomeGUID">
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\WOW6432Node\MyCompany\MyKey">
  ...
```

Things seem to work fine for installation. However, when I uninstall, the registry key is not removed. I suspect this is not the correct way to add a registry key under `Software\WOW6432Node`. My search on SO and Google haven't produced any results though. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WiX RegistryKey element documentation:

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrykey.html

Description
Used for organization of child RegistryValue elements or to create a registry key (and optionally remove it during uninstallation).

ForceDeleteOnUninstall  YesNoType   Set this attribute to 'yes' to remove the key with all its values and subkeys when the parent component is uninstalled. Note that this value is useful only if your program creates additional values or subkeys under this key and you want an uninstall to remove them. MSI already removes all values and subkeys that it creates, so this option just adds additional overhead to uninstall. The default is "no".

The otherthing to consider is this only happens if the component is being removed.  Logging the uninstall will give you more information on what's going on.